# Capacitance between P-type semiconductor block and metal plate

Tags: capacitance, semiconductor-physics

I have been trying to understand and simulate the capacitance between a P-type (doping= 10^15/cm^3) semiconductor block and a metal plate with air gap between them. I used Sentaurus TCAD software to simulate it.

What I'm not able to understand is how the capacitance depends on the thickness of the P-substrate. For eg., in the following configuration, Thickness of P-susbtrate: 700 um, air gap = 100 um and thickness of metal plate = 200 um, overlapping area = 1 mm^2 the capacitance is around 80 fF but when the thickness of P-substrate is made 350 um (with other parameters being the same), the capacitance is also halved to around 40 fF.

My understanding was that as long as you have sufficient charge carriers, the capacitance doesn't depend on the type or thickness of the material. For two metal plates with configuration above (air gap = 100 um, area = 1 mm^2 ), the capacitance is almost 80 fF. When a voltage of 10 V is applied, the resulting charge on the plates would be some 10^13 Coulomb which basically mean that we have some 10^6 electrons accumulated on the metal plates. Thus, 10^15 doping concentration should also provide sufficient charge carriers and thus capacitance should not depend on the thickness of the P-substrate.

Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: What does the software calculate the carrier concentration profile in the semiconductor to be?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My understanding was correct, the reason the capacitance was reducing with thickness of p-susbtrate was that the area was also getting reduced with the length.